# How to get header row alone in csv

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am in need of Query, Say I have "n" number of tables when I execute a script, it should give "n" number CSV with their header alone.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from <table> where 0 = 1`

and export the result to CSV, with headers included.